# Prevent wrapping of menu items

Tags: css

I created a horizontal navigation (menu) bar for my site. When I re-size my window to a size smaller than that of the bar, the menu items get wrapped. I want the menu to remain intact (that is, it should remain horizontal) irrespective of the size of window as it usually can be seen in sites such as Google. I tried various ways posted on various forums including this one but nothing worked for me. Below I have pasted my CSS code for the menu.

```
CSS CODE:

#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 70px; background-color: #6699CC; box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4); }


#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;

}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
   -moz-transition: color .15s;
     -o-transition: color .15s;
        transition: color .15s;

}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: #00FF00; }
body.home li.home, body.tech li.tech {font-weight:bold; }

#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}

#cssmenu ul ul a{
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
     -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}


#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}


#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(205,44,36);
    color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body class="home" background="teenscorner1.jpg" text="#FFFFFF" style="background-attachment: fixed">
 <div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
   <li class="home"><a href='home.jsp'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class="tech"><a href='tech.jsp'><span>Tech Specs</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Fun</span></a></li> 
   <li><a href="#"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>Wheelz</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When you don't know the width because the links can differ in width you could use `display: inline-block` on the list item `<li>` and `white-space:nowrap` on the list itself `<ul>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Frd8J/

Comment: be aware of the space between the items! you can remove the space by putting de li open tag against the closing tag. < /li >< li >

Comment: .I want that the menu should remain intact(that is, it shud remain horizontal) irrespective of the size of window as it usually can be seen in sites such as Google.

Comment: I mean to say dat when i resize the window, the menu items get shifted to next lines. I don't want this to happen. I want dat menu items shud remain where they were like when window was maximized.

Comment: I don't understand. The solution that @Gijs has provided works just fine for me and it's more flexible than mine.

Comment: Gijs, its not working for me. I pasted css of what you did. My problem still persists.

Comment: Gijs, its not working. 
Also when i resize the window to its minimum, it doesn't display a horizontal scroll. So I have 2 problems - 1. Menu items are wrapped on resizing window. 2. Horizontal scroll is not displayed when window is resized to minimum.
I want to prevent menu items from being wrapped and display the horizontal scroll.

Comment: I understand your problem but it's fixed when i open it... I see a horizontal scrollbar... and the menu items aren't wrapped. What browser are you using? and can you put your complete new code in a jsfiddle/dabblet? maby something is conflicting..

Comment: Gijs, i am using Google Chrome browser.
Did you try by downloading the code which you have given or just on jsfiddle?

Comment: Me too and I don't experience the problems you are having... please put your code in jsfiddle or dabblet

Comment: thanks man.. it worked.. i checked it again.. it was giving some error in your code (error regarding braces). I fixed it. Now,its working perfectly fine as I wanted. Thank you so much.
Could you please tell what was d problem with my code just for knowledge?

Comment: it was hard one to crack and its not a perfect solution :) you first used float and when you are using float it line breaks, a solution would be is giving the container a width but with a menu with items that differ in width you can fix it by saying the container shouldn't wrap the items so the line won't break. floats ignore that so i made the items act like text by giving them display:inline-block; sorry English aint my native language so i'm having difficulties explaining. Glad to be of help

Comment: Ok.I got what you did. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You should set a `min-width` for `#cssmenu > ul`, one that allows all your menu items to fit.

Comment: It should work, but I cannot tell why it doesn't in your case until I see the HTML.

Comment: ya it worked for u.. bt its not working for me.. i changed my css like u did.. bt d problem still persists.

Comment: Could you give us a link to the live site as well?

Comment: live site has not been developed fully yet. So, link to it can't be made available. Sorry.

Comment: does it have anything to do with viewing in offline mode and the one after uploading the site to some server?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work in my case but @Ana original answer did. I tried to add this as a comment to her answer but it would not fit. Putting a min-width on the UL as suggested, brought all of the LI items back to one line as desired, but that line extended to the right of the containing div. I added the same min-width to the parent div and I got what I wanted, all of the LI on one line within the container. As a final step, I removed the min-width from the UL (so this is a different, more general answer than Ana's) and everything still worked. In a nut shell if you make the UL nowrap in css as documented in the accepted answer and it wraps anyway, then make sure you give the list enough width so that it does not need to wrap. Another way to increase the width that also works (without using min-width) is to increase the width of the content area below the UL in the containing div. My case was a tabbed DIV, the LIs were the tabs on top. Each tab had content below it. When the content below was wide enough already the LIs stayed in one row. I could have put a min width on every tab content, but for me it worked better to put it once on the outside container. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

im assuming these are you nav bar items

```
<li class="home"><a href='home.jsp'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class="tech"><a href='tech.jsp'><span>Tech Specs</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Fun</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="#"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Wheelz</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
```

if you just put them like this

```
<li class="home"><a href='home.jsp'><span>Home</span></a></li>&nbsp;<li class="tech"><a href='tech.jsp'><span>Tech Specs</span></a></li>&nbsp;<li><a href='#'><span>Fun</span></a></li>&nbsp;<li><a href="#"><span>Deals</span></a></li>&nbsp;<li><a href="#"><span>Wheelz</span></a></li>&nbsp;<li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
```

thats all you have to do is join them all together with no spaces between the li end and start tags, now that would display them all in line with no spaces visually between your nav items on your loaded page, so you might not want them all to be visually joined like its one bar, so iv also put a code for a space in between the li end and start tags, this will give you a single space between all nav tags visually on your loaded screen but they will still stay tied together so that wont go staking up if you make screen narrow.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with my menu items wrapping to the next line. It took a few changes. First, I had to set the `<ul>` to have a max-height and overflow set to hidden. Then I just had to set a width to the parent container.

In my case, since the design is responsive and the area available changes (since the menu is flanked on both sides by elements with preset hard widths) I had to expand the area given as it grows.

```css
#primary-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 59em) {
  #primary-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 74%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  #primary-menu {
    width: 78%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 78.75em) {
  #primary-menu {
    width: 83%;
  }
}

ul {
  max-height: 53px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary-menu" class="menu">
  <ul class="menu menu__navigation--primary">
    <li class="first leaf active-trail">
      <a href="/equipment" class="active-trail active">Equipment</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <a href="/solutions">Solutions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <a href="/services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <a href="/locations">Locations</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <a href="/our-company">Our Company</a>
    </li>
    <li class="last leaf">
      <a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should give "display:flex" to "ul" tag