# CSS Horizontal Menu wraps when browser window shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal menu that looks fine when browser window is maximized but when i shrink the browser window or view page on phone the menu items wrap to a new line. I have tried every example online with similar issues with no success.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html" accesskey="3" title="">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="Policies.html" accesskey="4" title="">Policies</a></li>
      <li><a href="ContactUs.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="Strategies.html" accesskey="6" title="">Strategies</a></li>
      <li><a href="Testimonials.html" accesskey="7" title="">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="Tutorial.html" accesskey="8" title="">Tutorial</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

#menu ul
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li a, #menu li span
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0em 1.5em;
    height: 150px;
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.90em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    color: #ACCFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540268/prevent-wrapping-of-menu-items) have made the following changes:

```
#menu ul{white-space: nowrap;}
#menu li{display: inline-block;}
```

The "float: left;" on the "#menu li" is not necessary. The additional problem with your code is that the absolute positioning of the #menu prevents the x-scrolling, so if you really want a scrollbar that would have to be deleted.

See this [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87gc1298/) for a working example.

However, what seems to be more accepted practice is to avoid the ugly scrollbar on menus and make the menu collapsable for smaller screens. [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp) have a demo for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the menu wrapper a minimum width, like `min-width: 1225px;`
See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp79L0ft/).